# Unicode characters from Julia website

Tags: packages, fontspec, unicode, unicode-math, newunicodechar

In this link https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/unicode-input/ there is a list where you can directly use the unicode symbols:

**Code point(s);    Character(s);   Tab completion sequence(s); Unicode name(s)**

The *Tab completion sequence(s)* have also a name for direct command and *Code point(s)*. I have seen that exist also `emoji` package and similar.

I have this MWE that it is not works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%<-----"anguria"
\end{document}
```

My question is:

*How is it possible to use the symbols directly with the command or directly by copying them, either in text mode or in math mode??*

Comment: You are using latin modern and that font doesn't have watermellon characters. On this machine firefox uses Segoe UI Emoji there so you could use that (if you are n Windows)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for your support. I use unicode characters not so many times... one of the times I use emoji is in the comments that I take from this website.

Answer (score 1):

In text mode, load a font that contains the characters.  You should also put the command `\tracinglostchars=2` in your source file, so TeX will warn you if your current font lacks a character.

If you want to load a symbol from a font other than your main font, you can set the Unicode character active.  For example, let’s say you want to use the “tombstone” symbol ∎ for end-of-proof, as in some editions of DEK’s *The Art of Computer Programming*, and you want to use it from XITS.  You could write,

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newfontfamily\symbolfont{XITS}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qedqymbol}{{\symbolfont\symbol{"220E}}}
\newunicodechar{^^^^220e}{\qedsymbol}
```

In math mode, you are limited to the characters listed in [The List of Characters Defined by `unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf), but you can set the font used for any of them with `\setmathfont[range=....`  As with the previous example, you can set

```
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase,range="220E]
```

This lets you type either `\QED` or ∎ in math mode.  You can also use `\textnormal{...}` in math mode to use any text-mode symbol.

Comment: Hi, please, can you put an example to use some symbols from the Julia website? Thank you very much for all. +1.